# Decryption of a long byte array

Tags: c#, python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I would like to decrypt a long byte[], yet I can't managed to do that.

The receiving code: I read a `bitmap` directly from the stream (works as it is supposed to), then I convert it to `byte[]` using a `MemoryStream` and then I decrypt the whole `byte[]` and then the decrypted data is supposed to turn into a `bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bmpTmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(CommunicationHandler.GetStream());
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bmpTmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
string imageString = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(stream.ToArray());
```

By the way, the only reason I read the stream into a `bitmap` and then convert it to a `byte[]` instead of reading the stream right into a `byte[]`, is because I have not found any function that reads a `NetworkStream` right into a `byte[]`. 
I was wondering, how does `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream()` works? How come that this function reads the whole data? How does it know when to stop?

The decryption code:

```
public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherTextCombined)
    {
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                byte[] IV = new byte[16];
                byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipherTextCombined.Length - IV.Length];

                Array.Copy(cipherTextCombined, IV, IV.Length);
                Array.Copy(cipherTextCombined, IV.Length, cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd(); //The error occurs here: 
//System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is 
//greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection. 
            }

        return plaintext.TrimEnd('\0');
    }
```

The encryption code:

```
def encrypt(self, message):
    message = self.pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(str.encode(self.key), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)
```

The padding code:

```
def pad(s): 
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)
```

This is what I send over the NetworkStream:

```
import mss.tools

def screenshot():
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        return sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])

socket.send(mss.tools.to_png(image.rgb, image.size))
```

According to the error I get- `System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`, I think that the input is too long. This is the error stack trace: `at Project.LoadingImage.RunInBackground (Java.Lang.Void[] params) [0x0004d]`.

Note that the methods and the system work perfectly with simple and short inputs, yet the only problem is with the image, probably because the `byte[]` input is way too big, as the error implies.

Also, note that the decryption method returns `string` and not `byte[]` which makes it even more complicated to decode it to a `bitmap`.

As a conclusion, 3 main questions:

1. What does the error mean? How can I solve it?
2. How does `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream()` read the whole stream? How it works?
3. Is there any way to change the return type of the decryption function to `byte[]` from `string`?

Comment: Why are you subtracting the IV from the start of the cipher text?  The IV is used as an initial state within the AES algorithm, and is not included in the output message.

Comment: Both the IV and the Key are private items, known only to the sender and receiver. ONLY the encrypted data should pass through public channels.

Comment: As I understood, the IV does not have to be private. Since in every encryption a new random IV is produced, it is sent along with the message.

Comment: Anyways, this is not the issue. What should I do about the error?

Comment: The IV is not included in the output stream of the encryptor (it's a starting state, not data to be added). Unless you are somehow adding it back in then you shouldn't be try to subtract it during decryption.

Comment: Oops, i accidentally posted the wrong method. Updated.

Comment: "According to the error I get,..." Include the complete error message and/or stacktrace of the error/exception in your question.

Comment: As updated, your code works for me.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, the error is mentioned in the code, it seems to happen only when sending a lot of data at once (an image for example)..

Comment: *when sending...* OK, so maybe the error is in the way you are sending and/or receiving the data. Show that code too.

Comment: @SteveTodd That isn't completely true.  I'd argue it is common for the IV to pass through the communication channel also - recall that IVs are not secret and do not need to be protected, they simply must not be *predictable*.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I simply send a byte[] of a screenshot. I don't know if this would help but let me update the sending code. Also, I think that we go to the wrong directions because the encryption and decrypption work perfectly on short strings, it's just the image that causes the problems. Have you read the produced error?

Comment: We still miss the part where the stream is received or how the message text is padded during *encryption*.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace. At least the parts from where it was thrown down to your call to `ReadToEnd`.

Comment: This `Array.Copy` really buggers me. You can do entirely without, if you'd just looked at the constructors of the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes updated the whole questions, thanks.